# W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist, Phonegap with Android Studio

Tags: android, phonegap

i try to make my first android app with Phonegap. Everything works well but now i have a problem and could not found a solution. Maybe some of you could help me.
My Problem is that i try to call a php file to read some data from a MySQL DB. With localhost i have no problems. But if i try to call a php-file on a server i get the following message in the console:
"W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist: xxx" where xxx is my servername.
I found a few similar threads here and checked everything. my config.xml have the "" but it's still not working.
There are a few solutions for cordova but i cannot found anything for Phonegap.
Maybe some of you have an idea an can help me.

Thanks.
Alex

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried following plugin cordova-plugin-network-information and it's still not working. Could you please recommend a plugin? I cannot found any other which could be usefull.

Comment: ok, i have switched so cordova and installed the whitelist plugin. now everything works. don't know whats the difference between these two... so i have to read a bit more about all this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `cordova-whitelist-plugin`

To make PhoneGap add this plugin during build just add to your `config.xml` (inside `<widget>` tag) next line:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

My mistake, you dont need plugin.
Simple add following line to config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

which means enable network access to all domains.

You can also set for only specific domain: [Whitelist guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/)